# Efficiently factoring $n = p + 1 \pm 2a$, where $p$ is a prime formed by a sum of squares and $a$ is odd?

Tags: factoring, elliptic-curves

Let $p$ be a prime such that is $p=a^2+b^2$, where $a$ is odd, $b$ is even and $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

I have an integer $n = p + 1 + 2a$ or $n = p + 1 - 2a$, either of these may be given and chosen arbitrarily for convenience.

1. Is there an efficient way of factoring $n$?
2. Is there an efficient way of checking any integer $m$ in a certain range of integers $m_{min} < m < m_{max}$ divides $n$ evenly?

---

**Context**: This may be a case of an XY problem. I am asking this because I am interested in *quickly* finding elliptic curves of the form $E: y^2 = x^3 - kx$ over a prime field $\mathbb{F}_p$ with a cofactor $m$ being in a certain range. This is not used for cryptography. From theorem 4.23 on p. 115 of *Lawrence C. Washington*'s Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography, 2nd ed., we know that $\#E(\mathbb{F}_p) = p + 1 - 2a$ if $k$ is a biquadratic residue modulo $p$ and $\#E(\mathbb{F}_p) = p + 1 + 2a$ if $k$ is a square residue but not a biquadratic residue. Finding curves is therefore quick and efficient, but I fail to see any way to *factorize* it efficiently to find an $m$ in the pre-defined range $m_{min} < m < m_{max}$.

Comment: I'm looking at my keyboard, it should be asdfghjkl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial Answer**

*Describes factoring $n$ when $a, b$ are in special form.*

$$n=p+1±2a=a^2+b^2+1±2a$$

Let $b=2c^2$. Note that $b$ is even.

$$n=a^2±2a+1+4c^4$$
$$=(a±1)^2+4c^4$$
If $a±1=d^2$, $d$ even, $n$ can be written as
$$n=d^4+4c^4$$
Now $n$ has the Aurifeuillian factorization
$$n=d^4+4c^4=(d^2-2cd+2c^2)(d^2+2cd+2c^2)$$

Note that if $d$ is even, $a$ is odd and $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$.